# signing gmail with php imap

Tags: php, email, imap

My code

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= 'From: Me <me@gmail.com>' . PHP_EOL;
imap_mail('you@gmail.com','test',"$output","$headers");
```

Is there a way to sign the mail? when I use above code to test sending emails, I receive the email but I am getting the error

```
This message may not have been sent by: me@gmail.com  Learn more  Report phishing
```

[according to gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=180707) they attach signed data to the headers to authenticate

I am using gmail imap to send the mails

```
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password)
          or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
```

Is there a way to authenticate the email using php imap?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send mails as a Gmail user I recommend using the Gmail's SMTP. As IMAP is mainly used to receive mails from the inbox.

Here's how to send mails from Gmail's SMTP.

First

- Make sure the PEAR Mail package is installed.

  - Typically, in particular with PHP 4 or later, this will have already
    been done for you. Just give it a try. (Mail.php)

Then

**Sending Mail from PHP Using SMTP Authentication - Example**

```
<?php
 require_once "Mail.php";

 $from = "Sender <sender@gmail.com>";
 $to = "Recipient <recipient@gmail.com>";
 $subject = "Hi!";
 $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

 $host = "smtp.gmail.com";
 $username = "username@gmail.com";
 $password = "Gmail Password";

 $headers = array ('From' => $from,
   'To' => $to,
   'Subject' => $subject);
 $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
   array ('host' => $host,
     'auth' => true,
     'username' => $username,
     'password' => $password));

 $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

 if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
   echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
  }
 ?>
```

**Sending Mail from PHP Using SMTP Authentication and SSL Encryption - Example**

```
<?php
 require_once "Mail.php";

 $from = "Sender <sender@gmail.com>";
 $to = "Recipient <recipient@gmail.com>";
 $subject = "Hi!";
 $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

 $host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
 $port = "465";
 $username = "username@gmail.com";
 $password = "Gmail Password";

 $headers = array ('From' => $from,
   'To' => $to,
   'Subject' => $subject);
 $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
   array ('host' => $host,
     'port' => $port,
     'auth' => true,
     'username' => $username,
     'password' => $password));

 $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

 if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
   echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
  }
 ?>
```

Source [about.com](http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm)

Comment: Just note that Google's SMTP service tampers with headers in a way that does not conform with the relevant RFPs: http://lee-phillips.org/gmailRewriting/