# php smtp not sending email

Tags: php, smtp

```
    while (! file_exists('php') )
        chdir('..');

include_once "php/Mail.php";

    $from = "<me@gmail.com>";
    $to = "<you@gmail.com>";
    $subject = "Hi!";
    $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

    $host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
    $port = "465";
    $username = "foo@gmail.com";  //<> give errors
    $password = "xx";

    $headers = array ('From' => $from,
      'To' => $to,
      'Subject' => $subject);
    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
      array ('host' => $host,
        'port' => $port,
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password));

    $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

    if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
      echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
     } else {
      echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
     }
```

hello; i am using the answer that was given on s.o for smtp mailing; (believe its the first result if search)

yet i still do not receive the mail; can anyone help to spot any error or provide alt solutions? I have used the built in mailer but it is not being authenticated see -> [signing gmail with php imap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14180358/signing-gmail-with-php-imap)

Comment: I always use PHPMailer which is stable, bug-free, fast and working very nice. Easy to use too. Simple example [here](http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/send-e-mail-messages-via-smtp-with-phpmailer-and-gmail/)

Answer (score 0):

Is SSL enabled in your PHP ini file?

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```